# Assembly mov instruction without suffix

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I have the following mov instruction (without the suffix) from a disassembler.

```
mov %dx,(%eax)
```

What would be the instruction suffix? First I thought that the destination register determines the suffix, however according to the book I'm reading, I guess it's determined by the "smallest" register. So in this case would be

```
movw %dx, (%eax)
```

since %dx (16-bit word register) is the smallest one.
Is my reasoning correct? (Sometimes the CSAPP book is a little bit confusing, doesn't explain details clearly).

Comment: Generally, if the **size of the value to be transferred** can unambiguously be determined from the operands, you don't need a suffix. If it can't be determined (e.g. mov $123,(someaddrmode), where $123 can be 8bit, 16bit, 32bit or even 64bit), you must add a suffix. %dx is a 16 bit register, so it is clear you will be transferring 16 bits.

Comment: Got it!. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destination isn't a register in your examples, it's the source that's a register.  So the operand-size is 16-bit, thus AT&T would use `movw`.

The destination is 2 bytes in memory, selected by a 32-bit addressing mode.  `mov` requires both source and dest to be the same width.  If at least one operand is a register, that uniquely determines the operand size.

You need an explicit suffix for something like `mov $123, (%eax)` because neither operand is a register.

---

Your idea of "smallest" is totally bogus.  `movl %eax, (%bx)` is `movl` because the register operand is 32 bits, and the 4-byte destination is selected by a 16-bit addressing mode.

The register or registers in the addressing mode have zero effect on the operand-size.  Address-size and operand-size are independent, and you can override one but not the other.  (That's why there are separate machine-code prefix bytes for operand-size (`0x66`) and address-size (`0x67`).

Comment: Correct. Anything else wouldn't make much sense anyway, IMO.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks!